# socket hang up at TLSSocket.onHangUp when connecting to IIS6 server with TLS 1.0

Tags: node.js, request, iis-6, axios

This happens in various node version from v4 - v7, also in AxiosJS and RequestJS.

Typical error message:

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at TLSSocket.onHangUp
...
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out it's IIS6 uses (now) obsoleted ssl protocol which NodeJS's dev considered insecure to be listed as default `ciphers`

```
The connection to this site uses an obsolete protocol (TLS 1.0), andobsolete key exchange (RSA), and an obsolete cipher (3DES_EDE_CBC with HMAC-SHA1).
```

**To fix/bypass this**

In NodeJS, add `ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'` to request option.

In Axios, add below to request option,

```
httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
 ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
})
```

In request, add below to request option,

```
agentOptions: {
  ciphers: 'DES-CBC3-SHA'
}
```

See more at:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10900#issuecomment-273834289
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9845#issuecomment-264032107